# Make is running old/broken commands

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm running Lubuntu 12.10. My make file is named `makefile` and looks like this:

```
all: SquaresTesting.o Vector2d.o
    clang -o SquaresTesting SquaresTesting.o

SpringTesting.o: SquaresTesting.cpp
    clang -c SquaresTesting.cpp

Vector2d.o: Vector2d.cpp Vector2d.h
    clang -c Vector2d.cpp
```

I am in the same directory as that file but when I do `make`, it runs `g++    -c -o SquaresTesting.o SquaresTesting.cpp` (there are four spaces between g++ and -c; I've never done anything like that). It seems like changes aren't saving. I'm thinking either make crashed, my editor Geany done goofed, the filesystem is weird, or my SSD is corrupt.

Comment: Deleting the makefile and trying `make` returns this: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. Re-adding the makefile and trying `make` again results in the same ghost command of g++.

Comment: did you open the makefile with anything else other than vi ? --> the commands in the rules require a tab in from of them ...  check it with cat -e -t -v makefile it shows the line endings as $ and tabs as ^I .   Also try running with : `make -f makefile all `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor may have goofed or your filesystem might be weird or your SSD might be corrupt, but I typically find that when something doesn't work right the problem is most often that I made a mistake :-).

In this case, you have mistyped your target:

```
SpringTesting.o: SquaresTesting.cpp
```

You have told make that this rule will create `SpringTesting.o`.  But make is trying to find a way to make `SquaresTesting.o`.  Since you have no rule to build `SquaresTesting.o`, make tries to find one, and it does find one: there's a built-in rule to build any `.o` from a `.cpp`, and there does happen to be a `SquaresTesting.cpp` right there.

And since the default configuration for the C++ compiler is `g++`, that's what it uses.

If you fix your target to say:

```
SquaresTesting.o: SquaresTesting.cpp
```

you should be all set.  Of course, you could also take *advantage* of make's built-in rules; your entire makefile could be written as:

```
CXX = clang

all: SquaresTesting

SquaresTesting: SquaresTesting.o Vector2d.o
```

I'm assuming here that you wanted to link `Vector2d.o` as well, although your makefile doesn't show that.

Comment: If I used your makefile, how would I set flags?

Comment: What kind of flags?  There are built-in variables for preprocessor flags like `-I`, `-D`: that's `CPPFLAGS`, and also C flags like `-g` or `-O`, that's `CFLAGS`, and also C++ flags like... uhmm... `-g` and `-O` :-).  That's `CXXFLAGS`.  Then there are link-time flags like `-L`; they can go in `LDFLAGS`.  And there are library flags that go on the link line, like `-l`; they go in `LDLIBS`.

Comment: PS. Don't feel stupid.  The most critical skill for programming isn't 200 IQ, it's actually _attention to detail_.  Computers, unfortunately for us humans, are all about the details...